# JSON Path seems to be removing a comma

Tags: json, jsonpath

I'm using JSON Path to extract a some data from a json object.

The object looks like this:

```
{
   "properties":
      { 
         "random_field": "abc",
         "max value": "£35,900"
      }
}
```

My JSON path looks like this:

```
insert into display_paths (type,name,jsonpath) values ('type','Value (£)','$.properties.[''max value'']');
```

Annoyingly, this is returning the value without the ',', instead replacing it with a space:

```
Value (£): £35 900
```

Has anyone had a similar issue? Potentially it is a front end issue as opposed to a json path issue?

Comment: I've tested `$.properties.[max value]` in https://jsonpath.com/ and it works properly. Maybe it is a render issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note: Consider the risk of SQL injection when inserting unprepared data from external sources into an SQL statement like in your example. Read about [prepared statements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement), using them can prevent this.

---

About the jsonpath issue, looks like a quoting issue with your code. Check this working example:

```
import json
from jsonpath import jsonpath


data = json.loads('''
{
   "properties":
      { 
         "random_field": "abc",
         "max value": "£35,900"
      }
}
''')


query = "$.properties.['max value']"
# Note that this works too
query = "$.properties.[max value]"

print(data)
print(jsonpath(data, query))
```

Output:

```
{'properties': {'random_field': 'abc', 'max value': '£35,900'}}
['£35,900']
```

PS: `pip install jsonpath` must be run for this example to work.